# How to filter array values

Tags: php

I have a array like this, I need to filter only string keys from my array but i don't know how to do it, I am new for php please help me.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [0] => 2
            [status] => 0
            [1] => 0
            [user] => 86
            [2] => 86
            [project] => 0
            [3] => 0
            [task] => 36
            [4] => 36
            [day] => 06/30/2013
            [5] => 06/30/2013
        )
)
```

I want to make this array like bellow

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [status] => 0
            [user] => 86
            [project] => 0
            [task] => 36
            [day] => 06/30/2013

        )
)
```

can any one please tell me how to do it?

Comment: If you're getting these from a database result-set, I'd suggest only asking for associative results. How are you obtaining these?

Comment: yes I got from db but i haven't access for change it, this the way system gives output

Comment: @ChelzAdams It is the way how you collect the output. Not how the system (gues you mean the server) does "give" it you. Can you show us some more code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the best way but:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
   if(is_string($key)) {
      $new_array[$key] = $value;
   }
}
```

Where

```
$array
```

is your array.

This will rebuild your array to $new_array using only the elements that have a string as a key.

Comment: if(is_string($key)) { } yes this is good way, what i almost forgot, Thank you very much

Comment: no worries can you accept answer if it's what you were looking for? :P

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You seem to be using `fetch_array` try `fetch_assoc` instead</strike> (OP cannot change)

Well this is a fairly short amount of code that does what you want.. I'm working on a cleaner version though:

```
function removeNumIndex($val,$key)
{
    global $arr;
    if(preg_match('#^[0-9]+$#',$key)>0) unset($arr[$key]);
}
array_walk($arr,'removeNumIndex');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `fetch assoc` instead of `fetch array`

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting it from database, I suggest you use fetch_assoc

Try this:

```
$array    = array(1,"test"=>2,2,"tes"=>3);

$keys     = array_filter(array_keys($array), function ($k){ return !is_numeric($k); }); 
$result   = array_intersect_key($array, array_flip($keys));

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

now another solution

```
      $counter=0; $newarray = array();
            foreach ( $arrray as $key => $value) {
                      if($counter%2){  
                         $newarray["$key"] =$value;
                       } 
                $counter++
            }
```

print_r($newarray);

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternate approach, which is a little more descriptive in my opinion.

```
<?php
$array = array(
    0       => 0,
    'zero'  => 0,
    1       => 1,
    'one'   => 1,
);

class Filter extends FilterIterator {
    public function accept() {
        return ! is_numeric($this->key());
    }
}

$array = iterator_to_array(
    new Filter(new ArrayIterator($array)
));

print_r($array);

/*
    Array
    (
        [zero] => 0
        [one] => 1
    )
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

For example simple array like yours:

```
   $array = array(
      'id' => "2",
      '0' => "2",
      'status' => '0',
      '1' => '0',
      'user' => '86',
      '2' => '86',
      'project' => '0',
      '3' => '0',
      'task' => '36',
      '4' => '36',
      'day' => '06/30/2013',
      '5' => '06/30/2013'
   );
```

Ok. Now it's time for magic.

```
              \||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||/       
               |||                                            |||        
               |||                                            |||         
               |||      $response = array_unique($array);     |||
               |||                                            |||         
               |||                                            |||     
              /||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||\
```

You can visit [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)